# Identify missing dates for ID & Date table

Tags: sql, date, join, null

My approach to identify missing dates for IDs is to use a left table (t1) which is a calendar table of 100 years of dates and to LEFT join (on date=date) the master table (t2) which has date & ID .

I was hoping when I do the left join I would have a full list of dates ranging from 1-365 for each year in (t1) and then a joined id from (t2) when the dates match. When the date's are missing there should be a NULL.

The current output and the desired output from my script is attached here [desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGgHq.png)

Simplified script below:

```
SELECT t1.date,
       t2.date,
       t2.id   
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.date= t2.date
ORDER BY t1.date,t2.id ASC
```

Comment: On which database system are you? Can you use windows functions? There should be a simple solution, when you are looking for rows not having a date between a given start-date and end-date without your telly table t1, without a join and only a single table scan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want

```
SELECT t1.date, t2.date, t2.id
FROM t1 LEFT JOIN
     t2
     ON t1.date = t2.date and t2.id = 28295
ORDER BY t1.date, t2.id ASC;
```

If you want this for *all* ids (or a larger subset), use `cross join` to generate the ids and then `left join`:

```
SELECT t1.date, t2.date, i.id
FROM t1 CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT t2.id FROM t2) i LEFT JOIN
     t2
     ON t1.date = t2.date and t2.id = i.id
ORDER BY t1.date, t2.id ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
SELECT t1.date, t2.date, t2.id
FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.date= t2.date WHERE t2.ID = 28295 ORDER BY t1.date,t2.id ASC
```